# How access term name by object?

Tags: 8, taxonomy-terms

I want to load parent term name by tid .I am using this

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($tid);
kint($term);
```

This return a object which is my parent term but I am not able to access term name by this object. Please check attached screenshot of kint($term).
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should get the name with the getName method.
In your case :

```
$term[1]->getName();
$term->getName();
```

If not, you can load the term and after get the name:

```
$term = Term::load($term[1]->id());
$term->getName();
```

Comment: If i want get vid then ?

Comment: $term->getVocabularyId()

Answer (score 1):

```
$term = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage('taxonomy_term')->loadParents($tid);
$term_name = $term[key($term)]->getName();
```

jBlobsmith answer is not correct because he is using static term id ($term[1]) if parent's term id is 3 than it will not work.You have to change this key manualy in variable ($term[3]).

Comment: If i want get vid then ?

Comment: That's why I specified "In your case"...

Comment: $term[key($term)]->getVocabularyId();